# Redirecting specific path

Tags: 8, redirection

Is there a method to catch all the redirections on my site that contains an certain path on drupal level? I want to change the domain of those to an external URL.

For example when there is animal in the path it should link to an external URL: www.example.com/animal?small=frog => www.example2.com/animal?small=frog.

Comment: You can use [Match Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/match_redirect) module for redirection of url.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can redirect to a external domain with that module. Also I'm using drupal 8 so unfortunately it won't work anyway.

Comment: I would look into using a RouteSubscriber to alter or add routes based on the path, and then the route can do a Redirect. That's probably what Match Redirect will need to do in Drupal 8.

Comment: That's pretty much what the Drupal 8 patch to Match Redirect does:  https://www.drupal.org/node/2478179